# Import error when importing torch

Tags: python, pytorch

I didn't make any change but it suddenly doesn't work.

```
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cheng/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I tried `pip install numpy -I` but it didn't work.

My OS is Mac OS X, and I tried to install by both pip and conda. Reinstall the env didn't work as well.

pytorch version 0.3.1

numpy version 1.14.2

Solution:

Do not name your file tokenize.py!

Comment: How do you install pytorch. What is your system? Does `pip install -U numpy` work you?

Comment: @jdhao No it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution according to OP:*

A file named `tokenize.py` in the current directory caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd same error and I [solved it with change version of numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730012/4439762).

Result of `import torch`

$ python

Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import torch

** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number 3 had an illegal value

** On entry to DGEHRD parameter number 2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number 2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number 4 had an illegal value

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Projects\Aspose\lib\site-packages\torch_init_.py", line 190, in
from torch._C import *

**ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import**

Result of `import numpy`

import numpy

** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number 3 had an illegal value

** On entry to DGEHRD parameter number 2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number 2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number 4 had an illegal value

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Projects\Aspose\lib\site-packages\numpy_init_.py", line 305, in
win_os_check()

File "C:\Projects\Aspose\lib\site-packages\numpy_init.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
raise RuntimeError(msg.format(file)) from None

RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\Projects\Aspose\lib\site-packages\numpy\init.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.

**Solution**:

`pip uninstall numpy`

`pip install numpy==1.19.3`